# What actually happens in this code? I use the Python Turtle library to draw the fireworks, and I try to use random RGB color

Tags: graphics, draw, drawable, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

```
import turtle
import random
t = turtle.Turtle()
w = turtle.Turtle()
t.speed(0) 
w.speed(0)
w.penup()
t.penup()
def randcolor():
    col1 = random.randint(0,255)
    col2 = random.randint(0,255)
    col3 = random.randint(0,255)
    randcol = (col1, col2, col3)
    return randcol
def drawfw1(angle):
    x = random.randint(0, 100)
    y = random.randint(0, 100)
    t.goto(x, y)
    t.pendown()
    for _ in range(random.randint(30,100)):
        t.fd(200)
        t.left(angle)
    t.penup()

def drawfw2(angle):
    x = random.randint(0, 100)
    y = random.randint(0, 100)

    w.goto(x, y)
    w.pendown()
    for _ in range(random.randint(30,100)):
        w.fd(200)
        w.left(angle)
    w.penup()

while True:
    for _ in range(2):
        t.pencolor(randcolor())
        w.pencolor(randcolor())
        angle = random.randint(99,179)
        angle2 = random.randint(99,179)
        drawfw1(angle)
        drawfw2(angle2)
    t.clear()
    w.clear()
```

**This code is to program the random drawing firework**

> I actually trying to do something with this, and I know it was right.
> But then, the visual studio is not working and the turtle library
> also. How can I fix this problems.

Comment: "But then, the visual studio is not working and the turtle library also". What does this mean exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be due to a common turtle color error.  Turtle supports two color modes, with the RGB values as integers from 0 - 255 or as floats from 0.0 to 1.0.  *The float mode is the default.*  To switch to the other mode, you need to do:

```
colormode(255)
```

Below is a simplification of your code with this fix.

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
from random import randrange

def randcolor():
    red = randrange(256)
    green = randrange(256)
    blue = randrange(256)
    return (red, green, blue)

def drawfw(angle):
    x = randrange(100)
    y = randrange(100)

    turtle.goto(x, y)
    turtle.pendown()

    for _ in range(randrange(30, 100)):
        turtle.forward(200)
        turtle.left(angle)

    turtle.penup()

screen = Screen()
screen.colormode(255)

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.speed('fastest')
turtle.penup()

while True:
    for _ in range(4):
        turtle.pencolor(randcolor())
        angle = randrange(99, 180)
        drawfw(angle)

    turtle.clear()
```